# Updating MyDomain in Sandbox

Tags: apex, sandbox, mydomain, organization-wide

Does updating MyDomain in the sandbox affect MyDomain settings in production?

The documentation makes me think not, but it does noy explicitly callout whether the deploy to users buttons will deploy MyDomain on that sandbox instance or if this is an org level change.

Documentation:https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.identityImplGuide.meta/identityImplGuide/domain_name_testing_and_rollout.htm

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Sandbox and Prod are 2 different environments. Whatever you do in Sandbox won't cause any havoc in production unless you deploy it and that includes enabling or changing MyDomain.

My Domain once enabled cant be turned off without raising a case with Salesforce support.

But enabling it in Sandbox should be safest.